# MPMoviePlayerViewController crash OpenGL error 0x0505 in -[ES1Renderer resizeFromLayer:]

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipod

I am having an issue where when loading an intro movie at the start of my IOS application, the game will crash with OpenGL error 0x0505 in -[ES1Renderer resizeFromLayer:].

My movie specs are:

Dimensions: 480 x 320
Codecs: H.264, AAC
Duration: 00:15
Total bit rate: 984
Size: 1.9 MB

I start the movie on applicationDidFinishLaunching and do my CCDirector and EAGLView initialization/creation in a separate method which gets called after the movie finishes playing.

This works on simulator as well as Iphone 4, 3GS, Ipod 4th Gen, but on Ipod 2nd gen (Version 4.1) it crashes.

I have my own class that is derived from MPMoviePlayerViewController and have my own method called startMovie which does this:

```
- (void)startMovie
{    
    MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayerController = [self moviePlayer];
    moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    // Only play video for iOS above 3.2
    if(OS_Version > 3.21)
    {        
        [moviePlayerController setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
        [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
        [moviePlayerController play];
    }
    else
   {
        // Use the new 3.2 style API
        if([moviePlayerController respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
            moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        else // Use the old 2.0 style API 
        {
            moviePlayerController.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;  
            [moviePlayerController play]; 
        }
    }
}
```

When starting my movie I do is like so:

```
self.moviePlayerViewController = [[[PFMPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]] autorelease];
[moviePlayerViewController startMovie];
```

I believe I am running out of memory since the OpenGL error 0x0505 is an out of memory issue, but I don't under stand why. The game itself allocated more than 2 MB after hitting the play button, so I would think it could handle the movie allocation.

Is there anything glaringly wrong that I may be doing to cause OpenGL to throw an error like this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better off using the [CCVideoPlayer class](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCVideoPlayer) from the [cocos2d-iphone-extensions](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions) project, rather than re-inventing the wheel.